# How to parse all Facebook targetings with Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to parse with Graph API job titles(but problem exist for other methods) with method type=adworkposition.

```
def getJobs(job):
    URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adworkposition&q=' + job + '&limit=10000&locale=ru_RU&access_token='+TOKEN
    response = requests.get(URL)
    response = json.loads(response.text)['data']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response)
    return df
```

When job = 'developer' I expect to see at least a list of **Java Developer, Game Developer, .NET developer**, because I know for sure that they exist cause I see them in Facebook Ads Manager.

And also [an example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search#demo) from the documentation says that it works that way. But it does not and request returns only ".NET developer". What do I do wrong? Maybe there some regex which I don't know?

Comment: I am getting “Java Developer” and “.NET Developer” returned when I make that request using my own user token in Graph API Explorer …

Comment: Still there are a LOT more job titles with string 'developer' and I cannot get them.